# Event not working after clearing observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout event bound to a button:

```
<button type="button" id="uBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-preview-file-type="text" data-bind="
                            click: upload,
                            visible: files().length > 0 && !anyErrors() ">
</button>
```

When i remove a single item from my observable array in my view model every is still working correctly:

```
this.removeFileItem = function (elem) {
        self.files.remove(elem);
    };
```

.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-bind="click: $parent.removeFileItem, visible: !isUploading()">&times;</button>
```

Its only when i try to remove all items that i start running into issues:

```
this.clearUploads = function() {
    if (self.uploaded && self.files().length > 0) {
        //self.files.removeAll();
        //self.files([]);

        /*for (var i = 0; i < self.files().length; i++) {
            self.files.remove(self.files()[i]);
        }*/

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.files(), function(item) {
            self.files.remove(item);
        });
        self.upload = false;
    }
}
```

As soon as i clear the observable array my click handler on my 'uBtn' no longer works. As you can tell above i've trying to clear the array in a variety of ways and it hasn't made a difference. Even if there is only 1 item to clear and i'm essentially clearing it the same way with `self.files.remove()` then if i clear it with the 'clearUploads' function then the even longer works but if i clear it with 'removeFileItem then everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's this line:

```
self.upload = false;
```

Your click handler on the button in the first snippet above is bound to `upload`, seems that you then set it to `false` which will overwrite whatever function is handling it, so when you click the button it no longer works.

Should it be

```
self.uploaded = false;
```

to match the initial `if` statement in `clearUploads`?

Comment: Thanks so much. Your exactly right. I was stomping on my own event. I guess its my fault for naming the variable so close to the name of the event. I think i need to rename it.